# select where like A% gives no results but %A does php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-like

My table is filled with a total of 40.000 rows with at least over 2.000 rows starting with the letter `A`.

Now my `SELECT` query does return some results when I use

```
$selectGames = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Games WHERE GameName LIKE '%A'");
```

But when I use :

```
$selectGames = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Games WHERE GameName LIKE 'A%'");
```

a total of 0 rows are being returned. Why is that?

Comment: did you insert A% like games names manually from phpmyadmin or by mysql_? because if manually then you need to check if those values have spaces in the start it happened with me :D:/

Comment: Ahh i got it , the whole table is indeed inserted by mysql and it inserted an empty space at the back of the names but not at the front but it does fix the problem

Comment: Gald it worked for u :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%A` means "where the end of the string is the letter A". `A%` is the opposite "a string that STARTS with the letter A"

```
       %A   A%
APPLE  N    Y
ABBA   Y    Y
GOUDA  Y    N
```

They're totally different matches, so your two queries are NOT equivalent.

As well, make sure that your table's collation is set to a case-insensitive match. If it's case-senstive, then `a` and `A` will be treated differently.

edit: as well, remember whitespace matters:

```
mysql> select 'gouda ' like '%a';
                    ^---note the space here
+--------------------+
| 'gouda ' like '%a' |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Fine fruit, fine music and fine cheese ;-)

Comment: yes i know it is not equivalent but why does the A% not work because that is what i need. i tried the %A as a test and that worked but i need it the other way around.

Comment: well, how many records do you have that actually END with the letter `A`? note that things like `abba[space]` will not match,b ecause that string ends with a space, not an `a`

Comment: i also tried it by making all the results uppercase and the A in the query aswell wich also resulted in 0 results

Comment: i am making a page where you can select a letter from the alphabet wich will take everything from the databse that starts with that letter

Comment: I'm wondering if OP's rows is setup like `abba,apple,axle` - Edit: Scratch that; OP entered space(s). [`As per comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292624/select-where-like-a-gives-no-results-but-a-does-php#comment37539172_24292624)